# Simple java AI response program?

Tags: java

Hi I have this program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HowAreYou {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        System.out.println("How are you?");
        input = in.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("I'm doing good!")) {
            System.out.print("That's great to hear!");
        } else if (input.equals("I'm not doing too well...")) {
            System.out.print("Aw I'm sorry to hear that");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?");
            input = in.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("good")) {
                System.out.print("That's great to hear!");
            } else if (input.equals("bad")) {
                System.out.print("Aw I'm sorry to hear that");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It works fine for the first two responses, and if you enter something other than that it prints "Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?" correctly, but I want it to take in a response again after printing that. At the moment after it says "Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?" it doesnt allow you to enter anything else.

Comment: You need to put that in a loop, probably a `do-while`, which can take a specific keyword to be used as the termination condition.

Comment: @user3657381, use loops

Comment: Why loops? This little program is correct (maybe with the exception of not closing the scanner). On my computer it works!

Comment: this is what i am getting from your program `How are you?
ok
Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?
good
That's great to hear!` isn't that correct

Comment: @Sanjeev yes that is correct, just for some reason after asking me Sorry I didn't catch that..., it doesn't let me input anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is, after `"Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?"` message you hit `enter key` to give the response and your program terminates. This is happening because `input.nextLine` consumes that and it does not match anything and your program exits.

you shall replace

```
System.out.print("Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?");
```

with

```
System.out.println("Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?");
```

so that you get to next line before your actual input. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the infinite loop. Something like this

```
while(true){

  // your code here...

  if(input.equals("exit")) break; 

}
```

This is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HowAreYou {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        /* loop which keeps asking for input  ends when user enters Bye Bye*/
        while(true){ 

        System.out.println("How are you?");
        input = in.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("I'm doing good!")) {
            System.out.println("That's great to hear!");
            break;
        } else if (input.equals("I'm not doing too well...")) {
            System.out.println("Aw I'm sorry to hear that");
            break;
        } else if (input.equals("Bye Bye")) {
            System.out.println("Bye Bye");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry I didn't catch that are you doing good or bad?");
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like it to only prompt you for more if the answer was not recognised

Comment: i have made the required changes now. It would now continue to ask for an input unless you enter a known input